# Google Visualization Table Column Width and Row Height

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a panel on my site that has a Google Visualization Chart (Table) with controls and custom style.  I have trouble with setting column width - somehow no solution works.  Where is my mistake?

My two solutions:

a) like in row 57/58 in the code:

```
data.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', 'width:150px;');
```

b) like line 134-145 in the code:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
  google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'sort', setWidth);
  setWidth();
});

function setWidth() {
  var title = 'Field4';
  var width = '500px';
  $('.google-visualization-table-th:contains(' + title + ')').css('width', width);
}
```

Also I didn't find any solution for limiting row height.  If you select one row (eg. with Field4 filter) then this one row will fill all the space.  Is there a way to limit row size to the content only?

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/my7p01e8/2/

Comment: the width is being set in many places on many elements (JS & CSS), there most likely is a conflict among all the elements, thus preventing the width of a specific column. try removing all width settings, except for a specific column. once the column width is correct, add back the others to see which causes the conflict. same goes for height, if the table has a specific height, and only one row is displayed, then the row will have the height of the table.

Comment: also, `jsapi` should no longer be used to load google charts, it is an old version and out of date, see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) -- _Please use the new gstatic loader from now on._

Comment: Thanks for these! 
I'll use gstatic instead of jsapi - I didn't realize changes.
I see now, that any container element that restricts the table size is problematic.
But my intention is to have a table which is bigger than the container (container size is given, no more space), and the table should have scrollbars in either direction (and I would like to pan in any direction).  
Instead, what happens is - the vapi reduces the size of the cells (disregarding width settings), any cell...

Comment: ... even if table is bigger than the container already - and content of cells doesn't have any influence either. :-(  Is there an example with a given container/space and a custom set (and kept) column width?  Logic something similar like CSS "overflow: scroll" property which, of course, doesn't influence font-size...?